# How to access the return value of a C function called by lua_pcall?

Tags: c, lua

I have this function:

```
static int generic_pcall_wrapper(lua_State* L, int (*funct)(lua_State*)){
    int narg = lua_gettop(L);
    lua_pushcfunction(L, funct);
    lua_rotate(L, 1, 1);

    int res = lua_pcall(L, narg, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
    if(res != 0){
        //handle error
    }
    return ??; // I would like to return 1 as in sum()
}

static int sum(lua_State* L){
    int a = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    int b = lua_tointeger(L, -2);    
    lua_pop(L, 1);   
    lua_pushnumber(L, a + b);
    return 1;
}

static int foo(lua_State* L){
    return generic_pcall_wrapper(L, sum);
}
```

I would like to have generic_pcall_wrapper() to return the value returned by sum().

Note that this function should take many different functions, and how they deal with the return values is unspecified, the only reliable value is the number returned by each of those functions.

Comment: Call `lua_gettop` before and after `lua_pcall`.

Comment: I edited the question. Please have a look again.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since this is a pure "C" question. And C++ is a different language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing which I don't quite understand is the need for [lua_pop](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pop) in the sum function. This call to lua_pop is quite unusual and not present in [the official examples](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_CFunction).

```
static int sum(lua_State* L)
{
  int a = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
  int b = lua_tointeger(L, -2);    
  lua_pop(L, 1); /* unusual, probably not needed */
  lua_pushnumber(L, a + b);
  return 1;
}
```

Regarding the original question, in the callback *sum*, the return value represent how many results have been pushed on the stack. This value is consumed by the Lua runtime and is not available to the user of the Lua API. So if this value is needed later by the API user, it is needed to save this value using the Lua functions.

With the Lua API, a natural way to do that would be to push it on the stack.

```
static int sum(lua_State* L)
{
  int a = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
  int b = lua_tointeger(L, -2);
  lua_pushnumber(L, a + b); /* push the result of sum          */
  lua_pushinteger(L, 1);    /* sum return 1 value on the stack */
  return 2; /* return all the values (sum) and then #values */
}
```

Then:

1. The generic wrapper get the number of returned values on the stack
2. The wrapper remove this special value from the stack
3. Return to the number of values to the caller

```
static int generic_pcall_wrapper(lua_State* L, int (*funct)(lua_State*))
{
  int narg = lua_gettop(L);
  lua_pushcfunction(L, funct);

  //push argument again, but above the function
  int stack_size = lua_gettop(L);
  
  for (int i = 1; i < stack_size; i++)
    lua_pushvalue(L, i);
    
  int res = lua_pcall(L, narg, LUA_MULTRET, 0);

  /* Get the number of values which have been pushed */
  int res_count = lua_tointeger(L, -1);

  /* Remove the number of values */
  lua_pop(L);

  return res_count;
}
```

Comment: Actually, by returning 1 in `sum()`, `lua_pcall()` will leave on the stack exactly that number (1) of elements. So we don't need to care about returning that number to the caller of `generic_pcall_wrapper()`, (and neither to care about `pop()` or whatever happens in `sum`) in order to give the caller that number of results (1 in this case). Nevertheless, you talked about how to get the returned value, which was (and still is) part of the question, so that's still a good answer. I just wanted to comment on this to add more thoughts for anyone else who might encounter this specific problem.

Comment: Yes you are perfectly right, if all the functions only return 1 value like sum, this code is too complicated. But by “Generic”, my understanding was that you need it generic for functions which can return  an undetermined number of values.

Comment: Probably I didn't explain myself well enough. Whatever the return value of `sum` is, `lua_pcall` will (by itself) leave on the stack exactly the number of elements as the return value of the function (`sum`, in this case). So returning the correct number of results is not a problem anymore, because calling `lua_gettop()` after `lua_pcall()` executed, will give you always the same number that `sum` (in this case) returned. So we don't need the return value anymore for this purpose.